# Hive returns no data for simple select on partitioned external table

Tags: hiveql

my select query is fetching me no rows on a partitioned external table.

i created an external partitioned table audit_test on a location /user/abcdef/audit_table/, i am loading .csv file by creating partitioned directory based on date.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE audit_test
(perm_bitmap_txt STRING, 
 blank_txt STRING, 
ownr_id STRING, 
ad_grp_txt STRING, 
size_bytes_tot INT, 
last_mod_dt STRING, 
last_mod_tm STRING, 
hdfs_phy_loc_txt STRING, 
reg_hdfs_loc_txt STRING, 
reg_hdfs_grp_txt STRING,
reg_hdfs_comp_txt string)  
PARTITIONED BY (data_ext_DT STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION 'user/abcdef/audit_table/';
```

Now my output location would be /user/abcdef/audit_table/data_ext_dt=20150203/20150203_audit.csv

when i run a simple select query i am getting zero rows

```
select * from audit_test where data_ext_dt = '20150203'
```

Answer (score 0):

i have to create the partitions manually by using alter command:

`alter table data_sec_audit_rpt_test add partition(data_ext_dt=20150203);`

it worked.